# В мобильных приложениях ВК возвращает закодированный api_result, при этом на ПК версии без проблем

Tags: php, вконтакте, url

Делаю приложение для ВК с поддержкой для мобилок. Юзаю get-параметр api_result для получение имени, фамилии и аватарки пользователя. С ПК все приходит корректно, но на мобильном приложение проблемы с кодированием url. Сколько мучался — никак не могу декодировать этот get-параметр, а он мне необходим. Кто сталкивался, кто как решал?

Первый скрин — ПК, второй — мобильный. Вывожу get-параметр api_result и навсякий случай вывел информацию о браузере, может пригодится

[image: ПК версия]

[image: Мобильная версия]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте к тексту применить http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php
Либо ищите параметр, который будет просить vk давать ответ без urlencode

Comment: Его первым делом заюзал, ни как не хочет работать. Примеры тоже искал, итог нулевой.

Comment: а можете ответ от vk не в виде картинки, а текстом скинуть?